# Probability with changing chance

Tags: probability

Hey guys I don't know how to phrase the problem I'm having but here goes:

Probability with changing odds and multiple tries

Basically, there's a number that starts as 0. Every change to the number (it can only go up by 1 or go back to 0) has a different type of odds.

I want to know the way to calculate the odds to make the number to go to 13, 14, 15 etc. with multiple tries.

The probabilities to go up a number when your current number is on the left go like this:

0        ->  100%

1         ->  97%

2           -> 95%

3         ->  93%

4       ->    92%

5     ->      90%

6   ->        88%

7 -> 82%

8          -> 80%

9         ->  78%

10        ->  40%

11        ->  30%

12       ->   20%

13        ->  14%

14       ->   10%

15         ->  6%

Tries can exceed 1000, I just want a way to calculate what's my % chance to get, let's say the number 14 with any x amount of tries.

I tried

97*95*93*92*90*88*82*8*78*4*3*2*0.14*0.1*x

But I'm honestly not sure it's the correct solution since with enough tries it exceeds 150% even while I don't get it (it's from a game so I can test it).

Comment: With something like this, I advise sampling.  If you write a program to do $10^5$ trials or whatever then A. you'll discover the answer and B.  you'll be able to vary the vector of probabilities.

Comment: To be clear: you can do it recursively.  If we let $P(n,k)$ be the probability of reaching $14$ with $k$ turns left, starting from $n$ then it is easy to see that $P(n,k)=p_nP(n+1,k-1)+(1-p_n)P(n-1,k-1)$ where $p_n$ denotes the probability of going up if you are on $n$.  You can then get what you want via backwards induction.  Though this too will require programming.  I still think sampling is better.

Comment: How about using a transition matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transition matrix:

\begin{array}{lllllllllllllll}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.03 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0.05 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.07 & 0.93 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.08 & 0.93 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.12 & 0.88 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.18 & 0.82 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.78 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0.3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0.2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.86 & 0.14\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}

Matrix entry $[i,j]$ is the probability of moving from $i-1$ to $j-1$ in one try. Note that I set $[15,15]$ to $1$, so that I could see the percentage of ending up at 14 or higher, as you will simply stay at $14$.

Raise this to the power of $x$, with $x$ the number of tries, and the resulting matrix will give you the probabilities of moving from $i$ to $j$ in $x$ tries. So just look at the first row when starting at $0$. I did this for $x=25$, and found that you have about $40$% chance of ending up at 13, and also about $40$% chance of ending up at 14 or higher when starting at $0$. If you want to know the chances of getting to 15 or 16, you'll obviously need to add some rows and columns. [Here](http://matrix.reshish.com/powCalculation.php) is a link to play with this yourself.

EDIT

I reread your question and see that I misunderstood the game: my matrix assumes that you either go up by 1 or stay at the number where you are. But your game rule says to either go up by 1 or go all the way down back to $0$. OK, no problem, use this:

\begin{array}{lllllllllllllll}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.03 & 0 & 0.97 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.05 & 0 & 0.05 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.07 & 0 & 0 & 0.07 & 0.93 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.08 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.08 & 0.93 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.12 & 0.88 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.18 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.18 & 0.82 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.22 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.78 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0.3 & 0 & 0\\
0.8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0.2 & 0\\
0.86 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.14 & 0.86\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}

Again, I assume that once you reach 14, you stay at 14, so this will tell us the probability of reaching 14 in $x$ tries or less. Now, of course, it is much harder to reach $14$ when starting at $0$, and I found that there is about a $1$% chance of reaching $14$ in $100$ tries or less.